# Change the value of 1 input into the value of another input on click

Tags: php, jquery

another JQuery question, I wanted to change the value of the hidden input based on the value of another hidden input. I'm having some trouble with this already. here's my code so far. This is not working but I think you can already get the idea of what I'm trying to do with this:

HTML code:

```
<div>
    <div id="search_result_fake_container">
    <div id="search_result_fake_div2"></div>

    <form method="GET" id="getattendees">
    <input type="text" id="search_result_fake2" value="<?php if(!empty($event_selected)){echo $event_selected;} else{echo "Select Event";}?>" name="event_name">

    <input type="hidden" id="search_result_fake2_id" value="<?php if(!empty($event_selected)){echo $event_selected;} else{echo "0";}?>" name="event_id">
    </form>

    </div>

    <div id="search_result_present_list2">

        <?php foreach ($events as $events1): ?>
        <div class="search_result_list_item2" id="search_result_item_12" style="text-align:center;"><?php echo $events1['event_name']; ?></div>
        <input type="hidden" id="event_id" value="<?php echo $events1['event_id']; ?>">
        <?php endforeach ?>

    </div>
    </div>
```

and the JQuery:

```
$("#search_result_fake_div2").live("click", function () {
        $("#search_result_present_list2").show("fast");
        $('body').one('click',function() {
            $("#search_result_present_list2").hide();
              });
             event.stopPropagation();

    });

    $(".search_result_list_item2").live("click", function () {
        $("#search_result_fake2").val($(this).html());
        $("#search_result_fake2_id").val($("#event_id").val());



        $("#getattendees").trigger('submit');
        $("#search_result_present_list2").hide();
    });
```

I use GET just to check if the values are moving and I'm not that sure if the line `$("#search_result_fake2_id").val($("#event_id").val());` is really working.

Comment: Use jquery .click() function and in there use .val();

Comment: ids should be unique,you are duplicating your id in foreach loop

Comment: Sibu, ohh, I've missed that part. hmm.. I need to plot a solution.

Comment: y dont you provide jfiddle..will be easy for us to work on..

Comment: CodeJack, for a challenge maybe? haha! kiddin', well I'm not that familliar using jfiddle, although I know it's use. sorry for that.

Comment: I'm kinda lost in this JQuery all over again. I made a solution using javascript instead which handles and changes the values. Jquery does not come in handy for me as of this time. Thanks for all of your help anyways. Will go back on the answers when I started revising my codes. Thanks again. :)

Answer (score 0):

Add the `event` parameter to your `#search_result_fake_div2` click handler, like so:

```
("#search_result_fake_div2").live("click", function (event) {
                                                       ^--------HERE
```

Because otherwise you will have a javascript runtime error when you try to use it later in:

```
event.stopPropagation();
```